# Why i can't use Open() from XlsIO on xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I use the Open from the Assets on xamarin then and i Open on the Workbooks when i build my app it stoped working but if i coding on normal Console it's working, What i forget ?

```
var asset = Application.Context.Assets.Open("test.xlsx");

new ExcelEngine().Excel.Workbooks.Open(asset);
```

https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/create-read-edit-excel-files-in-xamarin-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you could try the code below.

```
 string filePath="test.xlsx";
 using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
        {
            IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
            application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2016;

            var asset = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(filePath);

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(asset))
            {
                var inputStream = sr.BaseStream;
                //Open the Tab delimited CSV file
                IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(inputStream, "\t");
                IWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

                var s = sheet.Columns.Count();
            }
        }
```

The code works well on my side to get the Column count of the Excel.

If you want to use this in Xamarin.Forms, you could use the Dependency Service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction